# Typescript - Type is missing the following properties from type even though all options are defined

Tags: typescript

I've got the following Typescript definitions:

```
type TDisplayKey = "a" | "b" | "c";

const DISPLAY_KEYS: Record<string, TDisplayKey> = {
  A: "a",
  B: "b",
  C: "c"
};

const DISPLAY_KEY_TITLES: Record<TDisplayKey, string> = {
  [DISPLAY_KEYS.A]: "Ay",
  [DISPLAY_KEYS.B]: "Bi",
  [DISPLAY_KEYS.C]: "Ci"
};
```

And I'm getting the following error on `DISPLAY_KEY_TITLES` (In VSCode):

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<TDisplayKey, string>': a, b, c
```

I've clearly defined all three properties. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with `DISPLAY_KEYS`. A property of `DISPLAY_KEYS` is typed as `"a" | "b" | "c"`. Because of this typescript will not try to be more strict with the computed properties you can define.

You want to make `DISPLAY_KEYS` more specific. You can manually define the type as:

```
const DISPLAY_KEYS: {
    A: "a";
    B: "b";
    C: "c";
} = {
  A: "a",
  B: "b",
  C: "c"
}
```

That is unfortunately a lot of repetition. Another option is to use `DISPLAY_KEYS = { /*...*/ } as const` (soon to be available in 3.4) or you can use a helper function to help typescript infer the above type:

```
type TDisplayKey = "a" | "b" | "c";

const DISPLAY_KEYS = (<T extends Record<string, TDisplayKey>>(o:T)=>o)({
    A: "a",
    B: "b",
    C: "c"
});

const DISPLAY_KEY_TITLES: Record<TDisplayKey, string> = {
    [DISPLAY_KEYS.A]: "Ay",
    [DISPLAY_KEYS.B]: "Bi",
    [DISPLAY_KEYS.C]: "Ci"
};
```

Comment: Hi @titian-cernicova-dragomir! I'm trying out 3.4's as const feature as but i'm getting an error saying that 'NAME_OF_CONST' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here
Which is true. But, isn't that how it's supposed to be used?

Comment: @UriKlar If you want to refer to the type of a const you need to use `typeof name_const `

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I was actually trying to make a type equal one of the constant's values. Like how an enum works..

Comment: @UriKlar this should work :`let DISPLAY_KEYS = {
    A: "a",
    B: "b",
    C: "c"
} as const;
type DISPLAY_KEYS = typeof DISPLAY_KEYS[keyof typeof DISPLAY_KEYS]`. If it does not please post another question with the code, it's difficult to wriote a lot of code In commenst